# Format a string to have n spaces only between words in python

Tags: python, string, whitespace, adjustment

I am working with strings that have different number of spaces between the non-whitespace characters. The problem is that this strings form a category, and they have to be equal. I would like to format them to have exactly the same number of spaces between the non-whitespace characters, f.e. `1`, but this could be generalised to insert more spaces if possible. And there should be no spaces at the beginning and end.

Examples with `n=1`:

```
'a  b    b' => 'a b c'
'  a b   c  ' => 'a b c'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply `split` it and `join` the resulting list by space(es)

```
>>> " ".join('a  b    b'.split())
'a b c'
>>> "  ".join('  a b   c  '.split())
'a  b  c'
```

From [`str.split(sep)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) docs:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is
>   applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single
>   separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start
>   or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, `split` with default argument takes care of it

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this would be with `split` and `join`.

```
>>> (' '*n).join(s.split())
```

*Note : The `' '*n` is just for convenience in case of the need to join with many whitespaces in between.*

#driver values :

```
IN : s = 'a  b    b'
     n = 1
OUT : 'a b b'

IN : s = '  a b   c  '
     n = 2
OUT : 'a  b  c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
def spaces_btw_characters(word, spaces):
    return (' '*spaces).join(word.split())
```

Comment: Why?  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: First of all this is my first comment here as u could notice, and yeah its better to provide additional context but i felt like it wasn't necessary in this case while i just have 2 lines of code and it's obvious what those 2 lines do. But anyway thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Think of it like you are not only responding to the question owner, you are responding to everyone who will research the same subject later.

Answer (score 0):

We `yourstring.strip()` for string to finish spaces from start and end. You can use `join()` on your string to format string according to your need. Hope this helps you.